# It has no effect when I update Invoice in QuickBooks Online with The V3 SDK for .Net

Tags: .net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, invoice, quickbooks-online

When I want to update the balance in a Invoice, the code below is running normally without any error, but the balance doesn't change, why?

```
var queryService = new QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice>(context);
    IList<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice> list = queryService.Where(p => true).ToList();
    foreach (var invoice in list)
    {                  
        if (invoice.Id == order.Accounting.QBOID)
        {       
            if (invoice.Balance != order.Accounting.SurveyAmount)
            {
                Invoice invo = new Invoice();
                invo.Id = invoice.Id;
                invo = commonService.FindById(invo);
                invo.Balance = order.Accounting.SurveyAmount.HasValue ? order.Accounting.SurveyAmount.Value : 0; 
                invo.sparse = true;
                commonService.Update(invo);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Balance is a read-only field in Invoice. It can't be updated.

Ref [doc](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/invoice).

**Add**

[image]
Thanks

Comment: So how can i sync price or change something like balance etc.? I want to achieve the sync function between local program and QuickBooks and update the balance if they are different.

Comment: this behavior is consistent with QBO UI. PFA snapshot in the above post. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious about this also for tangfb's comment, anyone have an answer?

Comment: The amount is calculated based on the line items in the invoice. To make the balance match, update the line items to match.